# Stop activity (not finishing it)

Tags: android, for-loop

I have the below code, simply, when the button is clicked a new activity is opened. I need to make 2 checks:

1- If the edit text is empty, simply show an alert and don't open the activity (it works for me perfect)

2- If the edit text is not empty, simply shows an alert and don't open the activity (doesn't work for me) + that the for loop makes the alert appears 3 times (the number of the chars).

I tried to use finish(), but it doesn't help.
The same code I used in Java with (e.consume) and works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class Paal extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paal);
}

// Action the button PAST will do
// Show the result of paal in the past
public void openPaalPast(View paalThePast) {
    // Shows the past conjungtion
    Intent paalPastView;
    paalPastView = new Intent(this, PastOfPaal.class);
    EditText getTheVerb = (findViewById(R.id.editText1));
    String theVerb = getTheVerb.getText().toString();
    // If the text is empty
    if (theVerb.isEmpty()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setMessage("alert");
        alert.setTitle("No");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        alert.setCancelable(true);
        alert.create().show();
    }
    // If the text is not empty
    if (!theVerb.isEmpty()) {
        startActivity(paalPastView);
        char[] charArray = theVerb.toCharArray();
        for (char c : charArray) {
            if (!(c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setMessage("alert");
                alert.setTitle("Noo");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                alert.setCancelable(true);
                alert.create().show();
                break; // to stop the for loop (so that the alert will be shown only once.
                // finish(); //doesn't help much, it only kill the whole activity
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the EditText is not empty?

Comment: Only to show the alert message (only one time).

Comment: What is the purpose of your `for` loop by the way?

Comment: @Jerrol
It is to check if the text entered contains only specific letters. I don't want the text to accept any language except the letter of the language I need (Hebrew for example)

Comment: @AboelmagdSaadAboelmagd so what do you want to `finish()`?

Comment: @Jerrol
What I really try to do is that: if the text contains any letter other than Hebrew letters, so show an error message and don't start the activity. And if the whole text is containing only Hebrew letters, so open the activity. The answer I added works, but it only check the first character of the text entered, if the second character is not in Hebrew it continues and starts the activity.

Answer (score 0):

> 2- If the edit text is not empty, simply shows an alert and don't open the activity (doesn't work for me) + that the for loop makes the alert appears 3 times (the number of the chars).

If you don't want to open the activity and run the alert only once, then take out the alert from the loop and remove the startActivity.

```
public void openPaalPast(View paalThePast) {
    // Shows the past conjungtion
    Intent paalPastView;
    paalPastView = new Intent(this, PastOfPaal.class);
    EditText getTheVerb = (findViewById(R.id.editText1));
    String theVerb = getTheVerb.getText().toString();
    // If the text is empty
    if (theVerb.isEmpty()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setMessage("alert");
        alert.setTitle("No verb entered");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        alert.setCancelable(true);
        alert.create().show();
    } else {
    // If the text is not empty
        char[] charArray = theVerb.toCharArray();
        for (char c : charArray) {
            if (!c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0) {
                 startActivity(paalPastView);  // Here I want the activity not to start, so Is there a way to do so?
            }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Maihan, but maybe I didn't explain myself clear, I want the startActivity to happen only if the check of if          (!(c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0) pass, if not so only show the alert, so my problem here is with startActivity as well

Comment: @AboelmagdSaadAboelmagd Try the revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried it before, it does the work but the alert appears 3 times!

Comment: Do you want to do anything if `(!(c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0))` checked is not passed?

Comment: @AboelmagdSaadAboelmagd I revised the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the will to help :)  -- I tried something and it fixed my problem, you can find it in the answer I added under this comment.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem

```
        // If the text is not empty
        char[] charArray = theVerb.toCharArray();
        for (char c : charArray) {
            if ((!theVerb.isEmpty()) && (c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0)) {
                startActivity(paalPastView);
                break;
            } else if (!(c <= 0x05ea && c >= 0x05d0)){
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setMessage("alert");
                alert.setTitle("No");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                alert.setCancelable(true);
                alert.create().show();
                break;
            }
        }
```